# Programmatically determine if linqpad script running against production connection string

Tags: linqpad

When I'm running queries in Linqpad I'd like to do some extra checking when the query is being run against a production database, is there a way of detecting programmatically if the connection string that's active for the current linqpad script is marked as production?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can get the current connection information using:

```
 Util.CurrentQuery.GetConnectionInfo()
```

Which returns an object that contains a `IsProduction` boolean property, which is True if the connection is marked as such in the connection properties.